# What thread could this camera motor be?

Tags: motors, measurements, stepper-motor, standards, threads

Firstly, I am sorry that the title of this question isn't helpful. I have bought these motors for a project:

- [5V 7mm 2 Phase 4 Wire Stepper Motor](https://www.banggood.com/5V-7mm-2-Phase-4-Wire-Stepper-Motor-p-1154480.html?cur_warehouse=CN)

I assumed that the 1.7mm diameter threaded shaft would take an M1.7 nut, but it does not. Standard thread gauges haven't given me a good fit and I am thinking that this thread is probably some industry standard. The motors are designed to adjust the lenses in digital cameras, so does anyone know were I might find standards relating to this?

Alternativley, is there some list of common threads that I can just try all the 1.7mm diameter nuts to find a good fit? I have time and money but don't know where to look.

Answer (score 1):

There are some "exotic" thread sizes used for small instrument work. Note that for a specific diameter there can be more than one pitch. It is also possible that the thread is not metric.

[Metric fine pitch threads](https://www.engineersedge.com/hardware/metric-external-thread-sizes1.htm)

[image]